# Leipzig Districts and Parts of Districts in GIS-format

Tags: geospatial, city, germany, district

For a city of Leipzig (in Germany) I am looking for City Districts and Parts of City Districts in geospatial vector data format, that can be later loaded into GIS software, e.g. shapefiles, KML, GeoPackage etc. or anything that can be easily converted.

So far the best data is provided by OpenStreetMap, see [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/CuU).

My attempts to find free data failed after investigating the following sources:

- [Open Data (Offene Daten) der Stadt Leipzig](https://www.leipzig.de/buergerservice-und-verwaltung/unsere-stadt/statistik-und-zahlen/open-data/)
- [Leipzig Data website](http://leipzig-data.de/)
- [Ortsteile und Bezirke von Leipzig in OpenStreetMap einpflegen](https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=63969)
- [Open Data - Freie Daten und Dienste des BKG](http://www.geodatenzentrum.de/geodaten/gdz_rahmen.gdz_div?gdz_spr=deu&gdz_akt_zeile=5&gdz_anz_zeile=1&gdz_unt_zeile=0&gdz_user_id=0)

I have seen the related thread, but it does not fulfill my request:

- [Postal codes and city districts worldwide for download](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/971/postal-codes-and-city-districts-worldwide-for-download)

Any hints?

Comment: Have you tried requesting the data from the Leipzig city government? This page has contact information (including an email address) that looks relevant: https://english.leipzig.de/services-and-administration/leipzig-in-figures/geographical-situation-and-land-use/

Comment: @csk, I can try, but usually it costs something

Comment: Really? Here in the US I would expect such data to be provided for free, assuming they already have it in a shareable format so it doesn't require extensive processing on their end. Perhaps that's a cultural difference.